# What type of database should I use in diary app in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, database

It is also the first time to develop,
I want to make a diary app, but I don't know which database to use because I don't have basic knowledge of the database.
When I click on the calendar, I would like to post on that date
And I also need a picture that needs to be imported.

I can look for it even if I post this. I think it would be the fastest to ask. Thank you for reading my POST and hope everyone who reads has a nice day

Comment: try to use CoreData for post management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Answer: I would recommend persisting data on the users device instead of a cloud based database by using Core Data for the following reasons:

1. The content may be private or sensitive in nature, keeping it on the device is safer
2. Media attachments can become costly at scale, saving to device removes that burden from the developer

some cons of this route include the following:

1. Potential loss of Analytics by not using a cloud database such as Google Firebase
2. Cloud storage can be backed up in case the user loses their device (assuming they are not backed up via iCloud)

For a more thorough answer I recommend you provide more in terms of your objectives and audience.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have a little extra question.
If I want the information to remain according to the account even if the phone is changed, should I use Firebase? Or should I mix it with core data?

Comment: Firebase is cloud based so data is default available as a backup, whereas core data is device storage therefore dependent on user choice in data backup method. Ask this as a separate question to receive more feedback.